# Using owl-filter.js to filter through owl carousel items

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am using this plugin to filter through items in my [owl carousel](http://plugin.bearsthemes.com/jquery/OwlFilter/)

But it is not working, I have had various console errors, this is the current one: 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: initOwlEvent is not defined"

I have added the jquery.owl-filter.js in the footer of my page, and below this called the plugin using this script tag:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    /* animate filter */
        var owlAnimateFilter = function(even) {
            $(this)
            .addClass('__loading')
            .delay(70 * $(this).parent().index())
            .queue(function() {
                $(this).dequeue().removeClass('__loading')
            })
        }

        $('.btn-filter-wrap').on('click', '.btn-filter', function(e) {
            var filter_data = $(this).data('filter');

            /* return if current */
            if($(this).hasClass('btn-active')) return;

            /* active current */
            $(this).addClass('btn-active').siblings().removeClass('btn-active');

            /* Filter */
            initOwlEvent.owlFilter(filter_data, function(_owl) { 
                $(_owl).find('.item').each(owlAnimateFilter); 
            });
        })
    })
    </script>
```

This is how I initiate the owl carousel:

```
var OwlCarousel = function () {

    return {     

        initOwlEvent: function () {
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var owl = jQuery(".owl-events");
                owl.owlCarousel({
                    lazyLoad: true,
                    items: 4,
                    itemsDesktop : [1000,2],
                    itemsDesktopSmall : [900,2],
                    itemsTablet: [600,1],
                    itemsMobile : [479,1],
                    slideSpeed: 1000,
                    autoPlay : 5000
                });


            });            
        }


}();
```

My HTML

```
<div class="row parallax-counter-v4 parallaxBg" id="row_events">
  <div class="content container">
    <h2 class="title-v2 title-center">Events</h2>
    <div id="filter-container" class="btn-filter-wrap cbp-1-filters-text">
      <div data-filter=".event-1" class="btn-filter cbp-filter-item">Main Events</div> |
      <div data-filter=".event-2" class="btn-filter cbp-filter-item">The Venue</div> |
      <div data-filter=".event-3" class="btn-filter cbp-filter-item">Woodys</div> |
      <div data-filter=".event-4" class="btn-filter cbp-filter-item">Activities</div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-carousel-v1 owl-work-v1 margin-bottom-50 mobile-margin-bottom-10">
      <div class="owl-events">
        {exp:su_event:homepage limit="8"} {events}

        <div class="item news-v2 cbp-item event-{venue_id}">
          <div class="news-v2-badge">
            {if thumbnail_url == ""}
            <a href="/events/id/{event_id}-{url_name}">
              <img alt="" class="img-responsive lazyOwl" src="" />
            </a>
            {if:else}
            <a href="/events/id/{event_id}-{url_name}">
              <img alt="" class="img-responsive lazyOwl" src="{thumbnail_url}" />
            </a>
            {/if}
            <p>
              <span>{start_date format="%d"}</span>
              <small>{start_date format="%M"}</small>
            </p>
          </div>
          <h4><a href="/events/id/{event_id}-{url_name}">{title}</a></h4>
          <p>{description}</p>
        </div>

        {/events} {/exp:su_event:homepage}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: According to the original demo page, it is calling "owl" instead of "initOwlEvent", and "owl" is a variable that is declared earlier up in variable scope of the script, and set to a value of $( ... ).owlCarousel( ... )

In your script, your "initOwlEvent" does not appear to use a value of $( ... ).owlCarousel( ... ), and in fact your "initOwlEvent" is not declared in correct variable scope or earlier up in variable scope to be seen, because of the "not defined" error you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while working with WordPress theme. Owl theme displayed the same error as you have mentioned. I have added jquery at the header and the issue got solved I am not sure whether this will work for you but you can give a try. Also, check if the owl script files are included after jquery.

Answer (score 0):

for me, it's working...

```
$(function() {


    $.fn.owlRemoveItem = function(num) {
        var owl_data = $(this).data('owlCarousel');

        owl_data._items = $.map(owl_data._items, function(data, index) {
            if (index != num) return data;
        })

        $(this).find('.owl-item').eq(num).remove();
    }

    $.fn.owlFilter = function(data, callback) {
        var owl = this,
            owl_data = $(owl).data('owlCarousel'),

            $elemCopy = $('<div>').css('display', 'none');

        /* check attr owl-clone exist */
        if (typeof($(owl).data('owl-clone')) == 'undefined') {
            $(owl).find('.owl-item:not(.cloned)').clone().appendTo($elemCopy);
            $(owl).data('owl-clone', $elemCopy);
        } else {
            $elemCopy = $(owl).data('owl-clone');
        }

        /* clear content */
        owl.trigger('replace.owl.carousel', ['<div/>']);

        switch (data) {
            case '*':
                $elemCopy.children().each(function() {
                    owl.trigger('add.owl.carousel', [$(this).clone()]);
                })
                break;
            default:
                $elemCopy.find(data).each(function() {

                    owl.trigger('add.owl.carousel', [$(this).parent().clone()]);
                })
                break;
        }


        /* remove item empty when clear */
        owl.owlRemoveItem(0);
        owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [0]);

        // callback
        if (callback) callback.call(this, owl);
    }

    var owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        autoplay: false,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        items: 3,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        lazyLoad: true,
        margin: 10,
        responsiveClass: true,
        navText : ["",""],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                nav: true
            },
            600: {
                items: 3,
                nav: true
            },
            1000: {
                items: 3,
                nav: true,

            }
        },


    });




    /* animate filter */
    var owlAnimateFilter = function(even) {
        $(this)
            .addClass('__loading')
            .delay(70 * $(this).parent().index())
            .queue(function() {
                $(this).dequeue().removeClass('__loading')
            })
    }

    $('.btn-filter-wrap').on('click', '.btn-filter', function(e) {

       console.log('ddd');
        var filter_data = $(this).data('filter');

        /* return if current */
        if ($(this).hasClass('btn-active')) return;

        /* active current */
        $(this).addClass('btn-active').siblings().removeClass('btn-active');

        /* Filter */
        owl.owlFilter(filter_data, function(_owl) {
            $(_owl).find('.item').each(owlAnimateFilter);
        });
    })


})
```